# Going from one Jframe to a JPanel in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I have created a login form where users will enter their credentials and navigate to other frame. This frame to frame transition is working fine. But I also added a admin login from a invisible label in the bottom.

When the admin clicks the invisible label on the user login frame (NewJFrame), a custom login panel (Admin) should be opened.

But when I click the label, `JPanel` is not showing.

```
private void jLabel6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
    Admin o = new Admin();           // Admin is a login panel
    NewJFrame o1= new NewJFrame();   
    o1.add(o);                     // Throwing an Exception here

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Also, consider these [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513) to multiple frames.

Comment: What's the Exception that's getting thrown?

Comment: And where is this MouseListener code? From within NewJFrame (terrible name, btw)? Instead of trying to launch a new login frame for admins, perhaps just switch the layout. `CardLayout` would be worth investigating.

Comment: This mouse listener code is in frame (NewJFrame), on which there is a label jLabel6, on clicking it, a panel (Admin) should open.

Comment: @splungebob Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Comment: Then it appears that Admin extends JFrame (or some other subclass of Window) instead of JPanel. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding it on mouse click ? i think you should add it at start and on mouse click , just make it visible by yourPanel.setVisible(true);